# Setting up automatic password with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have setup Devise, I have set up the below code in my user.rb file

```
def self.create_auto_password
    generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
    self.create(password: generated_password, password_confirmation: generated_password)
  end
```

How can I get into the Devise registration controller to then call my new method which I have set up to auto generate a password?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the devise controllers after installing Devise by running the following on your command line:

```
rails generate devise:controllers
```

This will generate a 'Devise' folder in your controllers folder.  You can then modify the controllers as needed.  It sounds like you would like to modify the registration controller to add the auto-setting password.

You can find more docs on their .git page here:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: what do I pass in to get the registrations controller? I have tried `-c registrations`, `-c` but it keeps giving me `No value provided for option '--controllers'`